# Copying rows from multiple delta tables into one via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, shallow-copy

I have multiple delta lake tables storing images data. Now I want to take specific rows via filter from those tables and put them in another delta table. I do not want to copy the original data just the reference or shallow copy. I am using pyapark and databricks. Can someone please help me find the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is a view over the original table. Use [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html) to create it with necessary filter expression, like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW <name> AS
SELECT * from <source_table> WHERE <your filter condition>
```

Then this view could be queried like a normal table, but data will be filtered according to your condition.